# Свой шрифт в Tkinter(CustomTK)

Tags: python, tkinter, шрифты, customtkinter

Здраствуйте, хотел бы узнать у меня имеется шрифт Open Sans я бы хотел узнать как его можно было бы использовать в Custom Tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модуль tkinter.font предоставляет класс Font для создания и использования именованных шрифтов.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My Font")

font = font.Font(family="Open San", size=14, weight="normal")

label = tk.Label(text="Hello World", font=font)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tkinter")

font = ("Open Sans", 14)

label = tk.Label(root, text="This id 'Open Sans' Font", font=font)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```